# Backspace deletes only one letter in TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

```
OutlinedTextField(
            value = intro,
            onValueChange = { intro = it },

            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                focusedBorderColor = Pink, unfocusedBorderColor = Brown
            ),
            modifier = Modifier
                .bringIntoViewRequester(requester)
                .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                    if (focusState.isFocused) {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            delay(200)
                            requester.bringIntoView()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(30.dp, 5.dp)
                .height(150.dp),
            singleLine = false,
            maxLines = 5,
            textStyle = TextStyle.Default.copy(fontSize = 18.sp),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                imeAction = ImeAction.Done
            ),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }),
        )
```

I'm developing an Android app using Jetpack Compose. When I try to delete input texts in Textfield, holding backspace doesn't keep deleting character one by one, but only the last one, so I have to keep clicking the delete button.

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share how you use TextField?
Because based on Google documents there are some rules for managing TextField state (text value) that you must follow to have a better experience with it.
Here is the document link:
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5

Comment: From smooth  delete  you mean you want to  delete all the  text in  one click ?

Comment: Smooth delete means, if I keep pressing the delete key, all letters are deleted from the end. Thanks.

Comment: I've just upload my code. Thank you for the document.

Comment: Post your code instead of an image

Comment: OK, I've just done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already a know issue being tracked here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/220795133 . Anyway this is fixed in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.2.0-alpha04 version.